# Android PanesLibrary Background of the activity container

Tags: android, panes

I'm a new user of [PanesLibrary](https://github.com/cricklet/Android-PanesLibrary) but I'don't know how to show a personal layout on the background when the app starts. The code is like the example on the github without auto generated fragmentes and Example Fragment:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setPaneSizer(new ExamplePaneSizer()); //inner class like on the github example

    // Lets setup a menu and a first pane!
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        Fragment menu = new CatFragment(); //show list of categories
        setMenuFragment(menu);
    }
}
```

And this is the layout of ExampleActivity:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".SandboxActivity" >

<com.mapsaurus.paneslayout.PanesLayout
    android:id="@+id/panes"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" 
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Some Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</com.mapsaurus.paneslayout.PanesLayout>
```

The proble is that the TextView is not showed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved. Simply add a new Fragment

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setPaneSizer(new ExamplePaneSizer());
    // Lets setup a menu and a first pane!
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        Fragment menu = new CatFragment();
        Fragment instr = new InstructionFragment();
        setMenuFragment(menu);

        addFragment(menu, instr);
```

Comment: Can You explain better?

Comment: I wanted a custom actionbar for each fragment, and setHasOptionMenu() did not work, but i managet to do it. I am sending broadcast to the activity when the tabindex is changed.

Comment: Try a new question.. i can't help you